# Python loop and build a dict from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an input object like that :

```
inputListObj = [{"col1": "data1",
            "col2": "data2",
            "col3": "data3",
            "col4": "data4"
           }]
```

and two list :

```
list1 = [elem1, elem2, elem3]
list2 = [prop1, prop2, prop3]
```

I need to build an output list of dict with all the possible combination of my two lists (list1 and list2)

so an output like that :

```
[
{           "col1": "data1",
            "col2": "data2",
            "col3": "data3",
            "col4": "data4",
            "col5" : "elem1",
            "col6" : "prop1"
},
{
           "col1": "data1",
            "col2": "data2",
            "col3": "data3",
            "col4": "data4",
            "col5" : "elem1",
            "col6" : "prop2"
},
...
]
```

any proposition to achieve that in python ?

I tried this :

```
output = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        for data in inputListObj :
            data["uniq"] = str(uuid.uuid4())[:7]
            data["col5"] = x
            data["col6"]= y
            output.append(data)
print(output)
```

Comment: It is important that you show the community that you are also working to solve the issue. If you do, others will help as well. Now, it appears that you might have a typo in your expected output. Are you hoping for `"col5" : "list1"` or `"col5" : "elem1"`? In the final result is your array length 3, same as the length of list1 and list2?

Comment: yes thanks I uodated the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 for loop works for you. If you need combination more than 2-3 list dont do it with for loop. Checks out [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
inputListObj = [{"col1": "data1",
            "col2": "data2",
            "col3": "data3",
            "col4": "data4"
           }]
    
list1 = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']
list2 = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']

output = []
for e1 in list1:
    for e2 in list2:
        tmpObj = inputListObj[0]
        tmpObj['col5'] = e1
        tmpObj['col6'] = e2
        output.append(tmpObj.copy())
```